# php - detect if variable has only spaces or not

Tags: php, datetime, date, timezone

I have a variable, and I need to only add it to an array if it contains something other than spaces.

Up until now I had been using `$var != ''`. That only covers if it's an empty string. I need it to cover if it has spaces in it.

Comment: Related: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Double-Spaced.aspx ;)

Comment: use regex '\s*', which will match 0 or more spaces

Comment: @Cyber: Don't forget to anchor the regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will check if a string contains at least one non-whitespace character.  Whitespace includes spaces, newlines, tabs, etc.

```
trim($var) != ''
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [empty()](http://www.php.net/empty) ?

Comment: `empty()` is false for strings that contain whitespace (or anything else, naturally)

Comment: <strike>Interesting.  The documentation only mentions that it tests true for empty strings; it doesn't mention whitespace at all.  But it definitely does work. (@Michael: Not over here, on PHP5.)</strike>

Comment: @cdhowie Er; what test did you do? I tried `$foo = ' '; empty($foo);` and got `false` (PHP 5.2.14)

Comment: @Michael: I'm... I'm not sure... I'm attempting to repeat the same test and it is returning false now...

Answer (score 0):

```
trim($var, ' ') != ''
```